# SchduledExecutorService not executing UncaughtExceptionHandler when exception happens in the thread

Tags: java, scheduler, scheduledexecutorservice, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I am using ScheduledExecutorService which uses ThreadFactory to create new threads. However when some exception occurs in the scheduled task, the UncaughtExceptionHandler in the threadfactory is not executed. Why is it happening?

Thread factory is as follows:

```
public class CustomThreadFactory {
  public static ThreadFactory defaultFactory(String namePrefix) {
    return new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
      .setNameFormat(String.format("%s-%%d", namePrefix))
      .setDaemon(false)
      .setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomExceptionHandler())
      .build();
  }
}
```

The Exception handler:

```
public class CustomExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable t) {
    log.error("Received uncaught exception {}", thread.getName(), t);
  }
}
```

The main function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(
          CustomThreadFactory.defaultFactory("scheduler"));
  ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 20L,
          TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(1));

  scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
      () -> {
          executor.submit(() -> Thread.sleep(10000));
      },0,1,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

I am stating my exact issue so that it does not end up with being XY problem. In the above snippet, the blocking queue has size one and tasks are added to blocking queue every second. So on adding third task, the blocking queue executor gives `RejectionExecutionException` which is not printed by `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

Comment: RejectionExecutionException is handled by `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler` not by `UncaughtExceptionHandler` which is used only for exceptions raised during execution of task. ThreadPoolExecutor has constructor that allow you to specify your own RejectedExecutionHandler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a thread is about to terminate due to an uncaught exception the Java Virtual Machine will query the thread for its `UncaughtExceptionHandler` using Thread.getUncaughtExceptionHandler() and will invoke the handler's uncaughtException method, passing the thread and the exception as arguments.

UncaughtExceptionHandler will be called if the submitted task throws an uncaught exception but `RejectionExecutionException`  does not throw by the task itself. However, you can pass `RejectedExecutionHandler` to the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

```
    public ThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize,
                          int maximumPoolSize,
                          long keepAliveTime,
                          TimeUnit unit,
                          BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
                          RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
    this(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue,
         Executors.defaultThreadFactory(), handler);
}
```

ThreadPoolExecutor takes `RejectedExecutionHandler`  as an argument.

**EDIT :**

In your case `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is not called/notified because when you call `scheduleWithFixedDelay` does not execute your Runnable directly however it warps it in `ScheduledFutureTask`. Now when `executor.submit(() -> Thread.sleep(10000));`  throws an exception (in your case RejectionExecutionException ) it does not remain uncaught because `FutureTask#run` caught the exception and set the exception as Future result/outcome. Look at the part of `FutureTask#run`:

```
try {
    result = c.call();
    ran = true;
} catch (Throwable ex) {
    result = null;
    ran = false;
    setException(ex);
}
```

And `setException()` method set exception object to the `outcome` of `FutureTask`.

```
protected void setException(Throwable t) {
    if (UNSAFE.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, NEW, COMPLETING)) {
        outcome = t;
        UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, EXCEPTIONAL); // final state
        finishCompletion();
    }
}
```

Now the question can we get the exception/notification of the Exception somehow?

Yes, it is possible. When you call the `Future#get` on the Future the exception will be thrown however the `Exception` will be wrap in `ExecutionException`. Take a look at the `Future#get` method.

```
  public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        int s = state;
        if (s <= COMPLETING)
            s = awaitDone(false, 0L);
        return report(s);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private V report(int s) throws ExecutionException {
        Object x = outcome;
        if (s == NORMAL)
            return (V)x;
        if (s >= CANCELLED)
            throw new CancellationException();
        throw new ExecutionException((Throwable)x);
   }
```

I have seen all the methods available (submit, execute, schedule etc) on `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` wrap the `task` in a future task. So I think there is no way to be in case of exception through `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

However in the case of ThreadPoolExecutor if you submit the task using `ThreadPoolExecutor#submit` your `UncaughtExceptionHandler` will **not** be notified but if you use `ThreadPoolExecutor#execute` then `UncaughtExceptionHandler` will be notified as `ThreadPoolExecutor#execute` does not wrap your task in `Future`.

Comment: In this case, is not the actual task `executor.submit(() -> Thread.sleep(10000));` instead of just Thread.sleep(10000)? . And the RejectionExecutionException is thrown by submit function.

Comment: But I understood it. When RejectionExecutionException is encountered by JVM, it does not check for UncaughtExceptionHandler but only RejectionExecutionHandler.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar I got your point. I need to take look more deeply into code. I will let you know if I find anything.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar I have updated my answer. Please take a look. I hope it will help you. Thanks!!!