# UncaughtExceptionHandler for ScheduledExecutorService doesn't work?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice, uncaughtexceptionhandler, thread-exceptions

I have this code here. I was trying to get information about unchecked exceptions in `Runnable`s of a scheduler without using try catch or the `ScheduledFuture` to check for exceptions. I thought this would be the easiest way but it doesn't show any exception. Why isn't there any output visible?

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler handler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            System.err.println("Exception in thread "+t.getName()+":");
            e.printStackTrace();                
        }
    };
    
    ThreadFactory tf = new ThreadFactory() {

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = new Thread(r);
            t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(handler);
            return t;
        }
    };
    ScheduledExecutorService ses = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, tf);
    ses.schedule(()->Objects.requireNonNull(null), 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875739/exception-handling-in-threadpools

Comment: Why do you not check the returned `ScheduledFuture` instance to see, if the task executed successfully?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SchduledExecutorService not executing UncaughtExceptionHandler when exception happens in the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58318817/schduledexecutorservice-not-executing-uncaughtexceptionhandler-when-exception-ha)